# will silicone spatula be damaged by epoxy resin?

Tags: composite-resin

Will epoxy resin dissolve a silicone spatula, cake icing spatula?  Will it work well enough to get the job done without contaminating the resin?

Comment: make a test batch and find out.

Comment: Dude, can you pay for that or what?

Comment: You can buy the resin and a spatula and test to your heart's content.

Comment: What brand of resin are you using? Two part resin is compatible with most materials, haven't had any issues mixing it in solo cups. I think some applicators are even silicone to help evenly spread the pour.

Comment: The spatula won't be harmed. Nor will it do anything well. If you are trying to make a nice fillet, use an suitable old lightbulb for big fillets, or a mellon baller for smaller ones. They sell sets of filleting tools as well. There is an industry standard [yellow plastic epoxy spreader](https://www.google.com/search?q=yellow+plastic+epoxy+spreader&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&oq=yellow+plastic+epoxy+spreader&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.12322j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) that works well and can be cut easily for fillets. Hardened epoxy peels right off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silicone molds are often used for epoxy resin casting, so I don't see any problems.